# Installing Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to index data on Elasticsearch, my problem is;after run the "elasticsearch.bat" command, I able to connect to the server, all process well done.but after that I cant write anything to the command line.Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What does "I can't write" mean? Is there no blinking cursor? If yes, does your .bat not terminate correctly? Is there a blinking cursor, but the keyboard doesn't react? If yes, is something occupy the keyboard?

Comment: there is a blinking cursor, but I cant type anyting. I can access http://localhost:9200 on my web browser I thougt it means I connected.

Answer (score 0):

Thats Ok, you see the ElasticSearch console output. Just open an other console to make some input. Or start ElasticSearch as a service (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/setup-service-win.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no command-line input available for Elasticsearch. You can do operations on Elasticsearch by REST commands (or with a Client API in for example JAVA).

You can use CURL (application) to do REST operations in a command line.

You can use the the internet browser to do some HTTP-GET commands. You can also do other REST commands (PUT, POST, DELETE) with some Chrome plugins like POSTMAN.

There are some Elasticsearch plugins available to enable monitoring and management tooling that becomes available via the browser.

Please read the Elasticsearch documentation!

Answer (score 0):

For all operations on indexes, mappings, querying, etc, the Marvel plugin has the Sense REST API interface which is fabulous. Sense is wrapped within the [Marvel](https://www.elastic.co/products/marvel) plugin which is free for development.

It allows you to execute all possible ES API commands as JSON. We use it both as a way to prototype commands before implementing them in our ES client, and as a way to test very specific/boundary search scenarios.

There are lots of other cool plugins to help you manage your ElasticSearch, some of which are described [here](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/06/goodbye-sense-welcome-alternatives.html).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you type only `elasticsearch.bat`, it means you are starting Elasticsearch server in the foreground, that´s why you are seeing real-time logs in your terminal and hence you can´t type anything.

Now, leave that unclosed and open another terminal (no need to go to the Elasticsearch directory again) and just type 
 `curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'` but first make sure that      `curl`  is supported in your terminal, if not, you need to use another terminal that supports it, for example Git Shell for Windows.

Afterwards you can use this second terminal to do your indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Via terminal with command curl + XGET (or XPUT, XDELETE, XPOST) you can send commands to elasticsearch:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/your_index' -d '{
    "query":
    {
        "filtered":
        {
            "query":
            {
                "match_all": {}
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

You can also use the Chrome extension Sense, which can handle JSON configs (with handy history, nice highlighting).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood something:

- ElasticSearch runs as a http service, that the reason why you cant still using that console.

Solution: **just open another console**.

But, keep in mind you dont need to use a console, you can access it using any REST Client. Take a look at "Postman - REST Client" and "Sense (Beta)". Both are Chrome extensions.